# matlibplot plotting lines based on a matrix

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

New to both matplotlib and numpy.

I have a matrix that represents an L shape:

```
import numpy as np
L = np.array([[1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2], [2, 4, 4, 2.5, 2.5, 2]])
```

[image: L shape]

How do I plot this in matplotlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try a little advanced indexing:

```
plt.plot(*L[:, range(-1,L.shape[1])])
plt.xlim(0, 5)
plt.ylim(0, 5)
plt.show()
```

Or probably more naturally with `Patch.Polygon`:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_patch(Polygon(L.T, facecolor='None', edgecolor='C0'))
ax.set_xlim(0,5)
ax.set_ylim(0,5)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]